# How do I keep additional features in AKS updated?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have installed `Azure Workload Identity`, e.g. like that:

`az aks create -g myResourceGroup -n myAKSCluster --node-count 1 --enable-oidc-issuer --enable-workload-identity --generate-ssh-keys`

This has installed a mutating webhook that is of version `0.15.0` in `kube-system`. Now when the new versions will come out, how do I keep it updated?

Does this happen automatically or I would need to uninstall/install again or do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, addons are maintained by Microsoft. Any update/upgrades will be rolled out automatically.

As [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/integrations#add-ons):

> Add-ons are a fully supported way to provide extra capabilities for
> your AKS cluster. Add-ons' installation, configuration, and lifecycle
> is managed by AKS

Workload Identity is not even considered as an additional feature, but the same thing applies since it's a managed component of the cluster, and Microsoft is responsible for the lifecycle of it.

Generally, any out of box resource in the kube-system namespace is managed by Microsoft and will receive the updates automatically.